# Concatenate a constant string to each item in a List<string> using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, string-concatenation

I am using C# and .Net 4.0.

I have a `List<string>` with some values, say x1, x2, x3. To each of the value in the `List<string>`, I need to concatenate a constant value, say "y" and get back the `List<string>` as x1y, x2y and x3y.

Is there a Linq way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
List<string> yourList = new List<string>() { "X1", "Y1", "X2", "Y2" };
yourList = yourList.Select(r => string.Concat(r, 'y')).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I picked this as answer for the Concat, otherwise similar to most of other responses. :-)

Answer (score 7):

```
list = list.Select(s => s + "y").ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative, using `ConvertAll`:

```
List<string> l = new List<string>(new [] {"x1", "x2", "x3"} );
List<string> l2 = l.ConvertAll(x => x + "y");
```

Comment: thanks @Paolo, I have tested that this works fine too for my needs. Is there particular reason I should choose the "ConvertAll" approach over the "Select"?

Comment: @itsbalur: Not really, infact I used `ConvertAll` only because there were already several other select-based answers :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Select` for that

```
var list = new List<string>(){ "x1", "x2" };

list = list.Select(s =>  s + "y").ToList();
```